# Containers in elementor are displayed wrong, what can I do to fix it

Tags: wordpress, containers, elementor

Suddenly my website broke, I didn't change or add anything, but still my site is not displaying correctly. In wordpress elementor plugin it is displayed correctly. My webhost said something is wrong with the containers but I couldn't find anything to change to solve the problem(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBWR5.png),(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJSkC.png), (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iziz.png). My website name is [www.gravitywebz.de](http://www.gravitywebz.de). This is a hint my hosting-support-team gave me, maybe its helpfull [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sSh0.jpg). Thank you in advance for the help.